# elastic search file converting first letter of field to lowercase automatically

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch

I am trying to upload data on elastic search though java file.

```
@Document(indexName = "testinventorydata", type = "testinventory")
public class InventoryData {
    @Id
    private String id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Long, index = FieldIndex.analyzed)
    private Long invStoreId;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss")
    @Field(type = FieldType.Date, index = FieldIndex.analyzed, format = DateFormat.custom, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss")
    private Date InvDate;


    @Field(type = FieldType.Long, index = FieldIndex.analyzed)
    private Long InvSkuId;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Long, index = FieldIndex.analyzed)
    private Long InvCategoryId;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Long, index = FieldIndex.analyzed)
    private Long InvCount;
}
```

here I want to field name as it is, but while uploading the ES it is converting first letter to lowercase.

like InvCount -> invCount.
but I want field name as it is.

Comment: May you please tell if you are using spring-data-elasticsearch? Which version of it and which version of Elasticsearch? The described behavior should not happen, I think, it uses standard Java reflection API method [`getName()`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/1b0006f9f704064e836a75a87444004864873f00/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/MappingBuilder.java#L194) which just returns the field name as it is.

Comment: I am using Lombok for getter setters

Comment: I would look inside the generated `InventoryData.class` file with some [Java decompiler](http://jd.benow.ca/) and make sure that field names are the way you expect. If they are not, then those getter/setter methods might have messed things up.